# Kafka terminologies and concepts

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am very new into Kafka world, and i cannot find a simple clear definition of some concepts like

```
 - Broker, what is it ? how can i use it ? where it installed ? how 
        producer/consumer connect to it ?

 - zookeeper, what is it ? why it is needed ?
 - topic
 - producer
 - consumer
```

if any one can provide simple answer to this questions.

Comment: Read the introduction in the official documentation. If something is unclear, come back with specific questions (after searching for answers first). https://kafka.apache.org/intro

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty easy.

Refer to this playlist [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gg-VwXSRnmg&list=PLkz1SCf5iB4enAR00Z46JwY9GGkaS2NON)

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this document : https://kafka.apache.org/intro